# Javascript variable inside an @if of Laravel in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I use a javascript variable 'x' inside an @if of Laravel?
I tried to do it inside an @if and outside. Outside, it works perfectly, but I really need to do an action based on this condition.

```
var x = document.getElementById("IdPrize").value;

var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = "\
@foreach (\App\Prize::all() as $prize)\
    @if ($prize->id == "+x+")\
        <p>{{$prize->name}} is the choosen one!</p>\
    @endif\
@endforeach";
```

Is there an specific reason for me not getting the variable 'x' value inside @if and @foreach? What can be done for it to work?

If I do it like the code below, it works perfectly.

```
var x = document.getElementById("IdPrize").value;

var mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = "\
@foreach (\App\Prize::all() as $prize)\
        <p>"+x+"</p>\
@endforeach";
```

Thank you!

Comment: just do it in javascript: `if( {{$price->id}} == x ) { ... }`.
I think it does not work because it's evaluated one time when you request the file from the server as php code, so it does not interact with javascript code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.getElementById("IdPrize").value;

</script>
```

In Php script it return as a string so you need to conert yout foreach element id to string So concat with string,

```
@foreach (\App\Prize::all() as $prize)\
    @php $x = print( ' <script>document.writeln(x);</script> ' ); @endphp
    @if ($prize->id."" == $x)\
        <p>{{$prize->name}} is the choosen one!</p>\
    @endif\
@endforeach";
```

Comment: Hey, this function 'print': print( ' <script>document.writeln(x);</script> ' ); isn't working for me. The javascript part in my page doesn't show anymore. If I remove it, the code doesn't work as I want, but the javascript part shows up. Is there any other way? Thank you.

Comment: `$x = print( ' <script>document.writeln(x);</script> ' );` is utter nonsense. The return value of `print` is always `1`. You can't execute JavaScript in the browser and then return the result to the PHP program which generated the JavaScript on the server.

Comment: Yes there is a bug and print always return 1. but echo return actual value of js variable.